# React Image refresh, Firebase Hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, loading, firebase-hosting

So I built a website using react, the website got some images in it, now when running the app locally it works perfectly, but when uploading to firebase hosting, The first time I enter the website The Images are loaded and all is good, but if I press refresh button all the images are gone, If I press Hard refresh the images are coming back..
When I am building the react app with "npm run-script build" I do got a assets folder..

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

```
<Image
          // className="has-shadow"
          src={require("./../../../images/mockUp.jpg")}
          width={370}
          height={150} />
```

Comment: Are you getting the same behaviour on your local machine? (After building and opening the built files)

Comment: Nope when using my local machine the photos load normally, even after refresh..

Comment: Can you check network tab of Chrome DevTools? What resources are they fetching? Is there a change in image request URL for 1st & 2nd load?

Comment: When photos are good displayed the network does show them in the network tab, also when I refresh I can still see it.. but this time it wont display.. I think this is something to do with react maybe?

Comment: Probably yes, we can't debug without more info